# Método SaveChanges() retornar o Id do registro adicionado

Tags: asp.net-core, ddd

Tenho no meu RepositoryGenerico os métodos :

```
public virtual async Task Adicionar(TEntity entity)
{
    DbSet.Add(entity);
    await SaveChanges();
}

public async Task<int> SaveChanges()
{
    return await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

O método SaveChanges faz o retorno do ID gravado, como eu poderia pegar este retorno?

Exemplo na controller:

```
[Route("Fornecedores/criar-novo-fornecedor")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(FornecedorViewModel fornecedorViewModel)
{

     var dados = _mapper.Map<Fornecedor>(fornecedorViewModel);
     await _fornecedorRepository.Adicionar(dados);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var idGravado = await _fornecedorRepository.Adicionar(dados);
```

Conforme bem salientado por você, de acordo com a documentação da microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-3.1, o método **SaveChanges** ou **SaveChangesAsync** retorna o id salvo no banco de dados para a operação em questão.

Comment: Ok... eu edito a resposta acima ou crio uma nova ?